# Save SaleOrder programmatically

Tags: php, vtiger, vtigercrm

When I save a Product object I would like to perform/trigger a save() on a specific sales order via a workflow function.

I tried to use the  standard save function but all my products are deleted in the sales order:

```
$moduleName = 'SalesOrder';
$recordId = $salesOrderId;
$recordModel= Vtiger_Record_Model::getInstanceById($recordId,$moduleName);
$recordModel->set('mode', 'edit');
$recordModel->save();
```

Is there a way to programmatically perform a save on SalesOrder object?

Answer (score 0):

You have apply insert queries manually after you save event triggered and to do that first you have to get the previous Product Line Item data in array then after save event of SalesOrder apply insert query for array one by one. That same thing vtiger do.

Comment: Ok but my wish was to avoid to recalculate the total amount (included tax, rebate, etc..) manually and use an existing function.

So I found a solution with vtiger API, here is my code :

`include_once 'include/Webservices/Retrieve.php';
include_once 'include/Webservices/Update.php';

$wsid = vtws_getWebserviceEntityId('SalesOrder', $salesOrderId);            $data = vtws_retrieve($wsid, $current_user);
$data["productid"]= $entityData->getId();
vtws_update($data,$current_user);`

Comment: I think it does the same think first you fetched the data and then passing same to Update function. Just you have used web-service. Cool